# Parts footprint list in Orcad Capture

Tags: pcb, footprint, orcad

I intend to design my first PCB and i am using Orcad suite. So, i built the theoretical circuit and before proceeding to the next step i have to put the footprint values for each part. I have decided what parts i am going to use but i don't know how to find a list with the availlable footprints in Orcad Capture. For example i want to use the IC: CD4007CN which is a through hole 14 pin IC. In the IC's data sheet it says:

> 14-Lead Small Outline Integrated Circuit (SOIC), JEDEC MS-120, 0.150” Narrow
>   Package Number M14A

Do you know which footprint is this? Are you aware of any list with all the possible footprints i could search and match?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The footprint description you give is for a CD4007CM. The CD4007CN is a 14-Lead Plastic Dual-In-Line Package (PDIP), JEDEC MS–001, 0.300” Wide.  The letter suffix on most IC part numbers specify the package, and the codes may vary between manufacturers.  For PCB programs I've used, the appropriate footprint for the CN part would be DIP14, 14DIP, or something like that, but the name in your program could be whatever the library developer wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Danish OrCAD distributor has made a nice website for the students that explains all of these things with videos. The distributor is Nordcad Systems A/S, and here is the [link in english](http://www.nordcad.dk/dk/student-forum/front-page-02.htm) with all of the answers that you seek.

Answer (score 0):

OrCAD capture doesn't understand footprints (it's just a field that can be filled out as far as it is concerned). You have to manually enter a name that corresponds with the footprint name in your target layout suite of software. For instance if you are using OrCAD layout, make a list of the names of the likely footprints you may want to use from the layout library.

Other PCB suites will have a library you can interrogate but unfortunately there is no ability to browse a PCB library from layout in the basic form of layout.

Comment: IS there any list with availlable footprints so as to see the code and paste it in Capture? This is the only step left for me in order to continue to the next step

Comment: "The list" totally depends on what PCB layout tool you are targeting or going to use. If you don't know what PCB tool is going to be used there are no generic names that can fill-in the blanks. It depends on the PCB tool.

Comment: I use orcad suite. So i guess the next step will be using PCB editor. right? in some videos i saw there is another one "Orcad Layout" but i don't have this. It's the first time doing this proceedure that's why i am asking this basic stuff...

Comment: When you import your netlist into OrCAD layout it will ask ask you for footprints and you can select them on the fly. Once you have selected all the footprints (via this process) you can back-annotate all these selections into capture so you don't need to worry about manually entering the information. Anyway that's how I remember it.

Comment: What if i don't have Orcad Layout?

Comment: I have Orcad Layout Translator. But i think this is something different, right?

Comment: I don't know. It's been years.